# Spring boot wont call my dao

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting simple Null pointer exception which I am unable to resolve. 
Have tried debugging the application but it just wont go in the dao class where i want it to go. It shows : **Unable to Install breakpoint and Absent Line control message**. But as i learned from other questions on stack overflow this message was to be ignored ,so that I did.

**Details for issue:**

Exception :

> in test controller
>
> in create Service
>
> at com.service.DesignerService.create(DesignerService.java:20)  at
>   com.controller.HomeController.test(HomeController.java:26)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)in create service   java.lang.NullPointerException

My controller method :

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println( "in test controller");
        DesignerService obj = new DesignerService();
        try {
            obj.create();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "index";
    }
```

My service calling :

```
public void create (){
        System.out.println("in create service");
        Designer designer = getDesigner();
        designerDao.createDesigner(designer);
    }
```

And Dao where the debugger never reaches

```
public void createDesigner(Designer designer) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            String id = String.valueOf(session.save(designer));
            System.out.println("Designer ID :"+id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me run this project . Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sahil, you are missing details that are required to properly answer this question.  The null pointer exception is because designerDao is null, but without seeing how the designerDao is instantiated or injected it's impossible to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: Additionally, don't write classes like `DesignerDao`. Spring Data can autogenerate them for you from a `CrudRepository<Designer, ID>` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a object why don't you Autowire your service using

> @Autowired
>   private DesignerService obj

and where did you initialise this object  ***designerDao***